# iOS Change Story Board

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xcode-storyboard

My iPad App has two storyBoards - FirstStoryBoard and SecondStoryBoard 
I have a single ViewController

I notice that Under Project > Targets > Summary there is an option for specifying the MainStoryBoard and if I change this setting the correct story board loads correctly.

The Question - How can I change the behavior so that I can change between the first and second story board at run time.  In other words I want to

Answer (score 2):

First, create storyboard instance:

```
UIStoryboard *board = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:nil];
```

and then get first view controller from it:

```
UIViewController *vc = [board instantiateInitialViewController];
```

add as child view controller:

```
[self addChildViewController:vc];
```

or maybe (if you are in AppDelegate.m / application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method)

```
self.window.rootViewController = vc;
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Question - How can I change the behavior so that I can change
>   between the first and second story board at run time.

You can't switch the value of the Main Storyboard setting (specified by the `UIMainStoryBoard`  key in your Info.plist) at runtime, so do the next best thing: use a common storyboard or nib file that contains very little, and then instantiate the storyboard that you want using the `UIStoryboard` class. For example, you could use a simple nib file to create your app delegate, and have the app delegate's `-application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` load first view controller from the storyboard of your choice.